# Retaining Blank Fields in Python Using the Split Method

Tags: python

I have a tab delimited file that has entries that look like this:

```
strand1       strand2        genename        ID 
AGCTCTG        AGCTGT           Erg1          ENSG010101
```

However, some of them have blank fields, for example:

```
strand1       strand2         genename         ID 
AGCGTGT        AGTTGTT                         ENSG12955729
```

When I read in the lines in python:

```
data = [line.strip().split() for line in filename]
```

The second example becomes collapsed into a list of 3 indices:

```
['AGCGTGT', 'AGTTGTT', 'ENSG12955729']
```

I would rather that the empty field be retained so that the second example becomes a list of 4 indices:

```
['AGCGTGT', 'AGTTGTT', '', 'ENSG12955729']
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated you can explicitly split on tabs, but you would still need to cleanup the line endings.

Better would be to use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) which handles delimited files:

```
import csv
with open('filename.txt', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    headers = next(reader)
    data = list(reader)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split explicitly on tab:

```
>>> "foo\tbar\t\tbaz".split('\t')
['foo', 'bar', '', 'baz']
```

By default, `split()` is going to split on any amount of whitespace.

Unless you can ensure that the first and last columns won't be blank, `strip()` is going to cause problems. If the data is otherwise well-formatted, this solution will work.

If you know that the only tabs are field delimiters, and you still want to strip other whitespace (spaces) from around individual column values:

```
map(str.strip, line.split('\t'))
```

Comment: Yeah, I'll edit to remove the `strip()` so it's more general-purpose. This is all very dependent on the data being well-formatted, and is not necessary a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't give a parameter to the `str.split()` method, it treats any contiguous sequence of whitespace characters as a single separator.  When you do give it a parameter, `.split('\t')` perhaps, it treats each individual instance of that string as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

Split method without any argument considers continuous stream of spaces as a single character so it splits all amount of whitespaces. You need to specify an argumnet to the method which in your case is \t.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always looking for puzzles to which I can apply pyparsing, no matter how impractical the results might prove to be. If nothing else, I can always look through my old answers to see what I've tried.

Don't judge me too harshly. :)

```
import pyparsing as pp
item = pp.Word(pp.alphanums) | pp.Empty().setParseAction(lambda x: '')
TAB = pp.Suppress(r'\t')
process_line = pp.Group(item('item') + TAB + item('item') + TAB + item('item') + TAB + item('item'))

with open('tab_delim.txt', 'rb') as tabbed:
    while True:
        line = tabbed.readline()
        if line:
            line = line.decode().strip().replace('\t', '\\t' )+3*'\\t'
            print (line.replace('\\t', ' '))
            print('\t', process_line.parseWithTabs().parseString(line))
        else:
            break
```

Output:

```
strand1 strand2 genename ID   
     [['strand1', 'strand2', 'genename', 'ID']]
AGCTCTG AGCTGT Erg1 ENSG010101   
     [['AGCTCTG', 'AGCTGT', 'Erg1', 'ENSG010101']]
AGCGTGT AGTTGTT  ENSG12955729   
     [['AGCGTGT', 'AGTTGTT', '', 'ENSG12955729']]
ABC DEF   
     [['ABC', 'DEF', '', '']]
```

Edit: Altered the line `TAB = pp.Suppress(r'\t')` to what was suggested by PaulMcG in a comment (from a construction with a double-slash prior to the 't' in a non-raw string).

Comment: Nice - since tabs are significant here, you can remove them from the default whitespace characters using `ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(' ')`. For strings that contain significant `\ ` characters (that is to suppress the Python interpreter's conversion of '\t' to <TAB>) use raw string literals: `r'\t'`. These were added to Python to make regex easier to enter but they would work here too. And since I updated to Python 3.5, I've fallen in love with the stdlib's `pathlib.Path` class for reading/writing short files, composing file references using `Path(some_directory) / filename_str`.

Comment: I tried various ways of making raw string literals for tab work. Let me just say that success was elusive. :) If you look at some of my answers you'll see that I too have been evangelising for pathlib. Let's end the struggles with `listdir`, `walk` and `glob`! PS: I'd be open to an example for the tabs.

Comment: I was referring to your `'\\t'` strings, which you could write as `r'\t'`. I can't envision a way to embed a tab or newline in a raw string literal, since the whole point is to *not* interpret the backslash but to leave it in verbatim.

Comment: @PaulMcG: Changed according to my understanding of your comment.